# What's the significance of the dot in "bqr" in Danial vs the omission of the same in Genesis

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, aleph-bet-letters, parashat-bereishit, daniel-book-of

In researching the phrase "evening and morning" I noticed a very small difference in the Hebrew text between Genesis 1 (e.g. [1:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0101.htm#4)) and [Daniel 8:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3408.htm#14), where the latter has a tiny dot in the first letter of the word transliterated "bqr".

Does that change the meaning of the word at all?

Comment: Software Monkey, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Your links are giving me a 403. But these should work instead: http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0101.htm and http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t3408.htm.

Comment: @Alex: Strange; both links work from me with current FF.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: yep, you're right - I was trying with IE; it does work with FF. Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: Software Monkey, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1277), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: @Alex and Software Monkey, those links didn't work for me either, on FF, so I took the liberty of replacing them with bilingual Mechon Mamre links.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it doesn't change the meaning. The letter *bes* that starts that word appears with a dot in it usually, but without one after a word (in the same phrase) that ends in an [open syllable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_syllable). (Usually.) The pronunciation changes between these two forms, but not the meaning. It's not unique to this word, either, but true of all words that start with a *bes*, *gimel*, *dalet*, *kaf*, *pe*, and *tav*. It's also true in more generality than just word-initial positions (though not in complete generality) that one of those letters has a dot in it when appearing after a closed syllable and has no dot when appearing after an open syllable. The dot is called a [dagesh lene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagesh_lene).

Comment: Re "The dot is called a dagesh lene": to be more precise, I should say it's called a dagesh. Sometimes a dagesh forte appears in any of these letters after a closed syllable. But that's a whole 'nother story, not what the question was about, so I'll leave the answer as is.